# Prevent Android UI scaling

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, imageview, scale

Basically I have a series of imageviews within a linear layout. I've set each of the imageviews layout width and layout height properties to 100dp and 50dp respectively (I've also tried px instead of dp and I've tried changing the imageviews max size) but the imageviews continue to scale rather than staying at this fixed size.

I was just wondering if anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:background="@drawable/backgroundtop" android:gravity="bottom">
    <FrameLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/frameLayout1">
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView3" android:src="@drawable/base" android:layout_gravity="center"></ImageView>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center" android:paddingTop="50px" android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/buttonnews" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="123dp" android:layout_height="49dp" android:scaleType="center"></ImageView>
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_width="163dp" android:layout_height="49dp" android:src="@drawable/buttonevents"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What device are you testing this on and what is your minSdkVersion/targetSdkVersion set to in your manifest? If you omit both of these declarations Android assumes your app targets API 1 at runtime and scales your UI to emulate a 320x480 screen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set scaleType of ImageView to fitCenter?